# OpenGL - selective world rendering

Tags: opengl, glut

I'm building a miniature city with the basic minimum looks of a city (roads,buildings,trees etc) where u can move around. I know that rendering the whole model set in each frame doesn't work...

So can anyone give me an insight on the standard (but easiest) procedure used in selectively rendering only the visible parts of the system? I mean, just displaying only the visible stuff (with respect to the camera position) and not rendering the unseen part.. 
Im using VC++ and GLUT API.

Comment: There are many ways of doing this. Frustrum culling (only draw what's in the view port), occlusion culling (only draw stuff not totally obscured) to name but two. There's also partial rendering techniques were you start drawing and then stop when you hit the threshold time for this frame.

Comment: Thank u @christian.. I'l check out those.. Does OpenGl provide predefined functions to aid any of these methods? or are we supposed to implement the algorithms from scratch?

Comment: It's been a little while since I was active in 3D graphics, so I'm not completely up to date, but it's largely up to you to decide what to send down the pipeline.

Comment: @itsraining Such high-level scene mamagement facilities are not the scope of OpenGL. But actually OpenGL performs frustum culling (rather called view volume clipping there) after the vertex processing stage. This is the reason why only the vertex stage (T&L, or vertex shader) profits from frustum culling and neither the rasterization nor fragment stage (textureing or fragment shader). But of course also the CPU-side profits from lesser draw calls. And OpenGL also supports occlusion queries, which are rather low-level but can be used to implement occlusion culling techniques.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frustum_culling) provides a very basic introduction to the field of culling techniques.

A good starting point and one of the easiest techniques is view frustum culling. With this method you check for each object in your scene if it is inside the viewing volume (viewing frustum). This basically amounts to checking for some simplified bounding volume of the geometry (like a box or a sphere, that completely contain the geometry) if it lies inside the viewing frustum, defined by six planes.

This can further be optimized by grouping objects by their position and create a so-called bounding volume hierarchy, this way you e.g. first check if a whole city block is inside the viewing volume (by using a bounding volume that contains the whole block) and only if it is, you further check the individual houses.

A more complicated technique is occlusion culling, which means checking if an object is completely hidden behind another object. Because these techniques can get substantially more complicated it should (if done) actually be done after the view frustum culling. OpenGL has hardware occlusion queries that can aid you in determining if an object is actually visible, but they require some additional work to work well. Especially for cities there may be special two-dimensional occlusion culling techniques (long time ago I heard about that, don't know).

This is just a very broad overview, feel free to google for individual keywords. It is always a good idea to carefully weight if the additional CPU-overhead is worth it (especially with complicated occlusion culling techniques), considering that nowadays the trend is to batch as many geometry as possible into a single draw call (by the way, I hope you don't use immediate mode `glBegin/glEnd`, otherwise changing this to vertex arrays or better VBOs is the first point on your agenda). But view frustum culling might be a nice and easy starting point, especially if the city gets rather large.

Answer (score 0):

Google "binary space partition trees".

BSP trees are a good means of determining what should be rendered from the camera's view angle and position.  The old-school first-person shooters, i.e. Quake *et al*, used them (or at least some derivation of the principle).

Here is a good [FAQ](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/graphics-programming-and-theory/bsp-tree-faq-r657).

Other good resources: 
[link](http://cgafaq.info/wiki/BSP_tree_construction)
[link](http://jsomers.com/bsp_demo/mazebsp.html)

Comment: The classic BSP tree that partitions polygons is a complete no-go on nowaday's "try to batch as most as possible into a single draw-call"-optimized graphics hardware. And doesn't let the file ending ".bsp" fool you that it has anything to do with BSP-trees (maybe in the very farthest sense). These files should rather end with ".pvs", if you want.

Comment: Thank u guys for helping out and providing the links.. i think i'll go with frustum culling for now.. n maybe occlusion culling if i can handle the stuff..:)